# Given mean, standard deviation and skewness find the distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Given three non negative real numbers x, y, z for which I know their mean, standard deviation and skewness, is it possible to determine uniquely the three numbers?

It is quite straightforward for only a pair of numbers therefore I think it should be possible to expand to three numbers. However I wasn't able to come to a solution yet.

I have tried to solve the equations analytically, but I had no luck on finding a solutions.
I have also tried to standardise the distribution so that the solutions lie in the intersection of a plane (through the origin with norm (1,1,1)) and a shpere. Again l found it hard to visualize the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=k$.

Has anyone came across this and would like to show me the solution?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried writing out the three definition equations and solving them?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with *Mathematica* but the equations are mildly complex.

Here's just $x$, where $m$ is the mean, $s$ the standard deviation, and $k$ the skew:

$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\left(2 k^2-27\right) s^6}+4 k s^3}+\frac{3\
   2^{2/3} s^2}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\left(2 k^2-27\right) s^6}+2 k s^3}}+2 m\right)$$

and valid regardless of the sign on the data points.

Comment: Do you think the solution is also valid for possibly negative solutions? This is because we could simplify by assuming m=0 and s=1. Furthermore, is the solution unique?